# How to refer multiple sheets in case statements

Tags: excel, vba

## Goal and Problem

My goal is to restrict access to different worksheets according to the username that currently uses the excel file.

I will have a minimum of 14 users (1 admin and 13 heads of department) and each one will have different access do the multiple existents worksheets. The admin will have access to all worksheets while the heads of department will each have access to a worksheet only associated with their department and at least 2 or 3 other worksheets.

Currently, I'm able to grant access to one worksheet but, as I said previously, I want them to access multiple worksheets.

## What I've tried

I've tried to use arrays in multiple ways but none of them worked so far.

```
    Select Case Application.UserName        
        Case "User 2"
            Set GetAllowedSheet = Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"))
```

```
Dim ArrayOne as Variant
ArrayOne = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

    Select Case Application.UserName        
        Case "User 2"
            Set GetAllowedSheet = Sheets(ArrayOne)
```

I did some research on google but nothing seems to quite match what I'm looking for.

## Code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Showorksheets
End Sub
```

```
Sub Showorksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsAllowed As Worksheet

    If Application.UserName = "User 0" Then
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsAllowed = GetAllowedSheet
    wsAllowed.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsAllowed.Name Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

```
Function GetAllowedSheet() As Worksheet

    Select Case Application.UserName
        Case "User 1"
            Set GetAllowedSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Case "User 2"
            Set GetAllowedSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")
        Case "User 3"
            Set GetAllowedSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")
        '...
        Case Else
        '...

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could use a Dictionary object to store the name of each worksheet and then a numeric value related to it (0 would be only admin, 1 adming somebody else, 2 and so on, a hierarchy). Later on, when the user logs in, you could code what level of access the user got, loop trough dictionary, and hide/unhide if user's level is lower or equal to access level of that sheet.

Comment: Side note - you probably know this, but restriction like this can easily be bypassed.

Answer (score 2):

As @BigBen suggest, hiding/unhiding is not the best way, because it can be easily bypassed.

Also, I do not know if there are any other macros in that workbook that affect worksheets, but dealing with hidden worksheets while coding can be a headache.

But anyways something like this could help.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'A workbook must have always at least 1 visible worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim DictWK As Object
Dim UserLevel As Byte
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set DictWK = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ThisWorkbook
    DictWK.Add .Worksheets("ONLY ADMIN").Name, 0 '0 because only admin can have it
    DictWK.Add .Worksheets("ADMIN AND HEADERS").Name, 1
    DictWK.Add .Worksheets("ASSISTANTS").Name, 2
    DictWK.Add .Worksheets("EVERYBODY").Name, 99 'A workbook must have at least 1 visible worksheet, so make sure there is 1 always visible to everybody
End With

UserLevel = LVL_ACCESS("User 1") 'change this to however you detect the username

For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If UserLevel <= DictWK(wk.Name) Then
        wk.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        wk.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next wk

DictWK.RemoveAll
Set DictWK = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

User's level:

```
Function LVL_ACCESS(ByVal vUsername As String) As Byte
Select Case vUsername
    Case "User 1"
        LVL_ACCESS = 0
    Case "User 2"
        LVL_ACCESS = 1
    Case "User 3"
        LVL_ACCESS = 2
    Case Else
        'not recognized, no access
        LVL_ACCESS = 99
End Select
End Function
```

Uploaded a sample to Gdrive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mI3LQd8QxLDlMl1bzz5hCFIwdOFCS2Nc

Comment: Beat me by seconds. Interesting approach, I might take a more in-depth look at that.

Comment: @Plutian Not my best, but it may help. Anyways, as pointed by BigBen, it can be easily bypassed (just deactivating macros, or pressing ALT+F11)

Comment: Yeah hiding sheets isn't going to deter anyone with a little more than basic excel skills. But you'd be surprise of how many of them there are in a regular office. But if confidentiality is key, then another approach should definitely be considered.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I was in the process of commenting what BigBen just said and then you answered. Yes, I know this is easily bypassed but the main goal at the moment is to optimize visualization for each user because the excel file has a lot of sheets and many of them, as you said, already have other macros behind that can affect their content. It's not really a problem of confidentiality but even if it was most of the users are not "experts" (and even if they were they would be held responsible) and I also would take a different approach as Plutian suggests :)

Comment: @byteme Good. Just let us know if this answer worked for you.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The lower level will always have access to all levels after it correct? If I want only a head of department (HoD) to access his own worksheet (e.g. ws BSC_DPT just for DPT HoD and admin, ws BSC_DENG just for DENG HoD and admin, and so on) can I achieve that with this code?

Comment: With this code no. You'll need to adapt it. Because I've used numbers, the lowest number (0) will have access to everything (admin). But if you got different Hods, if one Hod is level 2 and another one is level 3. the Hod with level 2 will have access to same worksheets that Hod level 3. You'll need to customize the code with texts instead of numbers. Something like `2A,2B,2C` and so on. Check @Plutian answer, because you can create arrays of sheets for each HoD and thay may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way you set up your case select as a function, it's hard to change it into what you need, but not impossible. You are on the right track with using an array. Here is an approximation of what you will need to rework your code into:

```
Sub Shosheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim allowed As Variant

allowed = getallowed

Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For i = 0 To UBound(allowed)
        If allowed(i) = ws.Name Then
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            GoTo Nextloop
            Else
                If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next i
Nextloop:
Next ws
End Sub

Function getallowed() As Variant
Dim blah As Long

blah = 3

Select Case blah
    Case 1
    getallowed = Array("Sheet1")
    Case 2
    getallowed = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Case 3
    getallowed = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet5")
End Select
End Function
```

What this does is first of all, change your function to take an array to accommodate the selection of one or multiple sheets.

It will then iterate over all the worksheets, and over your array and match whether your worksheet name is present within the array. If so, unhide the sheet and go to next sheet iteration, if not, default to hiding the sheet.

Please note this will throw an error if you unhide the last visible sheet, so to prevent this the last sheet will be unhidden at the start, and hidden as and when necessary last. This prevents any sheet being the last to be hidden and throwing an error.

Also if you do not skip onto the next iteration when you have a hit in your allowed array, the next iteration will mismatch and hide the just unhidden sheet, therefore the `Goto.Nextloop`